# Cómo crear un cronometro con javascript y web worker

Tags: javascript

Necesito implementar un cronometro con javascript y web worker, alguien ha hecho este proceso ya?.

En el momento tengo el cronometro creado con javascript pero no he podido implementarle el web worker.

Código Javascript.

```
  var centesimas = 0;
  var segundos = "00";
  var minutos = "00";
  var horas = "00";

  function inicio () {
    control = setInterval(cronometro,10);
    document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
  }
  function parar () {
    clearInterval(control);
    document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
  }

  function reinicio () {
    clearInterval(control);
    centesimas = 0;
    segundos = 0;
    minutos = 0;
    horas = 0;
    Centesimas.innerHTML = ":00";
    Segundos.innerHTML = ":00";
    Minutos.innerHTML = ":00";
    Horas.innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = true;
  }
  function cronometro () {
    if (centesimas < 99) {
      centesimas++;
      if (centesimas < 10) { centesimas = "0"+centesimas }
      Centesimas.innerHTML = ":"+centesimas;
    }
    if (centesimas == 99) {
      centesimas = -1;
    }
    if (centesimas == 0) {
      segundos ++;
      if (segundos < 10) { segundos = "0"+segundos }
      Segundos.innerHTML = ":"+segundos;
    }
    if (segundos == 59) {
      segundos = -1;
    }
    if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0) ) {
      minutos++;
      if (minutos < 10) { minutos = "0"+minutos }
      Minutos.innerHTML = ":"+minutos;
    }
    if (minutos == 59) {
      minutos = -1;
    }
    if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0)&&(minutos == 0) ) {
      horas ++;
      if (horas < 10) { horas = "0"+horas }
      Horas.innerHTML = horas;
    }
  }
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes con el **Web Worker**? ¿Cómo estás tratando de crearlo? Necesitaríamos ver el **JS** con el que tratas de operar con él para poder saber que te puede estar pasando, a ciegas difícilmente se te podrá ayudar.

Comment: @Jassan,  Si usted muestra el trabajo que ha conseguido hasta ahora, podrían ayudarle mejor.

Comment: Ok, ya lo añado a la pregunta... Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí, creamos un script que cuenta. El script se almacena en el archivo `demo_workers.js`

```
var centesimas = 0;
var segundos = "00";
var minutos = "00";
var horas = "00";

var obj = []

function timedCount() {
    cronometro()
    postMessage({"centesimas" : centesimas,"segundos": segundos, "minutos":minutos,"horas":horas});
    setTimeout("timedCount()",10);
}
function cronometro () {
    if (centesimas < 99) {
      centesimas++;
      if (centesimas < 10) { centesimas = "0"+centesimas }

    }
    if (centesimas == 99) {
      centesimas = -1;
    }
    if (centesimas == 0) {
      segundos ++;
      if (segundos < 10) { segundos = "0"+segundos }

    }
    if (segundos == 59) {
      segundos = -1;
    }
    if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0) ) {
      minutos++;
      if (minutos < 10) { minutos = "0"+minutos }

    }
    if (minutos == 59) {
      minutos = -1;
    }
    if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0)&&(minutos == 0) ) {
      horas ++;
      if (horas < 10) { horas = "0"+horas }

    }
}


timedCount();
```

A continuación se muestra el código de la página HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .reloj{
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: monospace;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

<div id="contenedor" style="display: inline-flex;">
        <div class="reloj" id="horas">00</div>
        <div class="reloj">:</div>
        <div class="reloj" id="minutos">00</div>
        <div class="reloj">:</div>
        <div class="reloj" id="segundos">00</div>
        <div class="reloj">:</div>
        <div class="reloj" id="centesimas">00</div>

    </div>



<script>
var w;

function startWorker() {
  if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof(w) == "undefined") {
      w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
    }
    w.onmessage = function(event) {

      document.getElementById("horas").innerHTML = event.data.horas;
       document.getElementById("minutos").innerHTML = event.data.minutos;
        document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = event.data.segundos;
         document.getElementById("centesimas").innerHTML = event.data.centesimas;
    };
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
  }
}

function stopWorker() { 
  w.terminate();
  w = undefined;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te ayude, saludos.